# How can I increase width of Selection Margin or prevent block highlighting in Visual Studio 2010 text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mouse, highlighting

When I moved from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010, there seems to only be a small section of pointing space (for the mouse) to click and drag and click again, to grab a few lines of code.  This is about 8 pixels wide and is referred to as the Selection Margin.  I often used this area in Visual Studio 2008 to select/copy/paste code.  Now I have to rely on using the keyboard, which is not difficult, but if I'm using the mouse, Visual Studio is not very intuitive or usable.  Is there a way to prevent the highlighting of lexical groups (where the expand/collapse or plus/minus sections are) so I can just select the lines of code instead?  They seem to call this block highlighting.  Most of the surface area to the left of the text in Visual Studio 2010 seems to be dedicated to the block highlighting.  The text editor freezes when a lexical block of code is highlighted and I cannot use the right context menu.  The right context menu is also only available from inside the text editor now, so I have to select my lines in that 8 pixel region, then move my mouse over to the right to copy.  My productivity in Visual Studio 2010 has decreased substantially because of this change.

I'm wondering if anyone has written any extensions with the Visual Studio 2010 editor to fix these issues?
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/WriteExtensions.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why don't you highlight the lines from the right hand side?

Comment: Some code extends beyond the right side of my monitor real-estate, so I can't be certain I'm grabbing everything.  And when I paste, the spot where I starting clicking and dragging needs to match where I paste, doesn't it?

Comment: in the Visual Studio 2010 options, the area that I'd like to make larger is called the "Selection Margin" (Text Editor > General) .. it looks like the "Indicator Margin" is the space where you can debug symbol files.

Comment: If the line goes past the right hand side of your monitor, you can click and drag from above the line. It doesn't select the line above and when you paste, it should be in the right place. If the line above also goes past the right hand side, then you can use the left hand column (which I assume won't be everytime, so it might be okay for you). Alternatively, you could format the lines so that they don't extend past the real estate of the screen. I'm not sure of an option to extend the actual size of the Selection Margin.

Comment: It seems like when I click on the line above to start my selection, it requires that I start from a relative spot where I want to paste my code.  I think my question is already in this forum, but there's no solution for it.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vseditor/thread/55be12f4-8d3d-4c89-83f7-8c38ffc6e203

Comment: I think my largest concern is that if you try clicking in the region that dims the screen, the screen locks up and you can't do anything.  The amount of space for this to happen far exceeds the space that one can use for highlighting the lines and copying.  Also, when you copy you first have to put the cursor in the left Selection Margin, then move the cursor over to the code text and copy over there.  Copying from the spot where you selected (in the Selection Margin) is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Show line numbers. This allows you to have more space to select and copy the lines, but you still must go over to the right (where the code is) to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to select in a so called 'Continuous Stream Mode' which is supported by VS 2010 by default? Here's what I mean -> Hold down the SHIFT key and click in the Selection Margin(located at the far left of the Editor window, to select a whole line.) to extend your selection line by line.

Regards,
Evgenia

Comment: how is holding shift different from not?  After selecting the lines, I need to move my cursor to the code in order to copy.

Comment: I see, holding shift just allows you to continue on with the selection.  I think SHIFT+ArrowDown does the same.